# Delete current custom post from a button click with ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

My platform store multiple custom posts created by users. Now I am trying to create a delete button from where they can delete their own post . The ajax request is successful but I get the "Error: Unable to delete the post"

This is shortcode function

```
function wpso_delete_my_posts()
{
    $current_user =  get_current_user_id();
    $author_id = get_post_field('post_author', $post->ID);
    ob_start();
    if ($author_id == $current_user || current_user_can('administrator')) {
        echo '<a class="delete-post" id="send-to-draft-button" rel="nofollow" href="#">Delete Listing</a>';
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('delete_me', 'wpso_delete_my_posts');
```

This is ajax function

```
add_action('wp_ajax_send_post_to_draft', 'send_post_to_draft_callback');
function send_post_to_draft_callback() {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    wp_delete_post($post_id, true);
    die(); 
}
```

This is ajax request

```
$('#send-to-draft-button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: bbjs.ajaxurl, // Use the WordPress AJAX URL
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'send_post_to_draft', // Name of the server-side function to call
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    alert('Post has been deleted');
                } else {
                    alert('Error: Unable to delete the post');
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error: AJAX request failed.');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why would `response.success` exist, when you do not give any such response _from_ your `send_post_to_draft_callback` function ...? Go check out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json_success/

Comment: And of course you should not just give a success _response_, without actually _checking_ if the operation was really succeeded or not. You need to check what `wp_delete_post` actually returned.

Comment: `$post_id = get_the_ID();` - that also makes no sense. That function works within the WordPress Loop - not the context you are in here. You are not currently specifying _which_ post you want to delete, anywhere. You need to put the post id onto those individual links you are creating, and them pass that specific ID as a parameter in your AJAX request.

Comment: And of course you will then still need to check if the post actually belongs to the current user. Just because you only _create_ links for my posts, doesn't mean I could not manipulate that, and send you a request with a different post id, of a post that is not even mine.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it's not point of `response.success`, i just simplified the code, I had such as response from `send_post_to_draft` and I deleted it. 

From what I know, `get_the ID()` is giving the current post ID.

I checked the user and author of the post in `wpso_delete_my_posts()` function. If the user is not the authorof the post, the delete button will not be displayed at all.

The problem is that I used something similar for deleting current account and was working successfully. Just didn't use  `response.success`, but this will not change the result anyway.

Comment: I have this code which is working, but for another website
`add_action('wp_ajax_delete_user_account', 'delete_user_account');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_post_delete_user_account','delete_user_account');
function delete_user_account() {
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 wp_delete_user($user_id);
    wp_die();
}`

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('.fl-node-izv1fo45gt9x').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
  url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        action: 'delete_user_account', 
      },
      success: function(response) {
          window.location.replace("https://paparpakdev.wpengine.com/login");
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('An error occurred. Please try again later.');
      }
    });
  });
});
`

This is working

Comment: _"From what I know, get_the ID() is giving the current post ID."_ - within the WP Loop, yes. Not outside of it. You are not even in a context where there would _be_ anything to be called "the current post" - you are making this request to the WP AJAX endpoint URL, so there is no context whatsoever that any "current post" could be determined from. _"I have this code which is working"_ - getting the current user ID is a completely different kettle of fish, that will work in almost any context.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this at the end in case that somebody will need...

In my shortcode function I added the ID data attribute to refer the current post ID

```
<?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
<a class="delete-post" id="send-to-draft-button" rel="nofollow" data-post-id="<?php echo esc_attr($post_id); ?>" href="#">Delete Listing</a>
```

In AJAX function I modified the way of retrieve the post ID. Now the function looks like this.

```
function send_post_to_draft_callback() {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    wp_delete_post($post_id, true);
    die(); 
}
```

In the AJAX request I just declared the postId and added it to data.
The new funtion:

```
$('#send-to-draft-button').click(function(e) {
        let postId = $(this).data('post-id');
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: bbjs.ajaxurl, // Use the WordPress AJAX URL
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                action: 'send_post_to_draft', // Name of the server-side function to call
                post_id: postId
            },
            success: function(response) {
                window.location.replace("/buy"); 
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error: AJAX request failed.');
            }
        });
    });
```